# Extracting a column from every Frame in a Panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I have a Panel data containing some Data Frames. All of them have a column named 'N0'. I'd like to an array containing the means of N0 for every panel. I managed with this:

```
[np.mean(data.minor_xs('N0')[g]) for g in data]
```

But it seems too cumbersome. Isn't there any cleaner way to extract the N0 columnes, like data['N0']?

Comment: Please show structure of panel data. Is it a list of data frames? A stacked, large data fame with panel indicators? I see a good candidate for a `groupby()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.Panel.apply` [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Panel.apply.html) as illustrated with random sample data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
data = {'Item1': df1, 'Item2': df2}

df = pd.Panel(data)

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Item1 to Item2
Major_axis axis: 0 to 3
Minor_axis axis: A to B
```

which, as `DataFrame`, looks as follows:

```
                Item1     Item2
major minor                    
0     A     -0.572396  0.515488
      B      0.796982  0.726253
1     A      0.345817 -0.330810
      B     -2.516973  1.833602
2     A     -2.140583 -1.050717
      B      1.302233 -1.391122
3     A     -0.088435 -0.041199
      B      0.521575  0.618990
```

Using `.apply()` as below gives the `mean` for each `column` by `DataFrame`, the sample illustrates how to select only `B`.

```
df.apply(np.mean, axis='major').loc['B']

Item1    0.025954
Item2    0.446931
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Using a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame` instead might be simpler because better documented as it seems to be the more common use case.